# How to export excel file using PHP into Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, file-import

For Example :I have two tabs in excel file ID and Name tabs, I also create ID and Name tables in the DB. In these two tabs, also have associated Columns and Data. Now I would like to export this excel file through file upload UI[file upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jQbs.png) using **PHP** function.

How can I do for that please help me to suggest? Thanks [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqixw.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ArtOsi I would like to import excel file that insert all data rows to DB without inserting each rows using INSERT INTO to DB, that means I want to upload bulk data into DB using excel file

Comment: @P.Som: to do that, you need to be able to parse excel file in php code. Find a library that can do that. Or maybe export the excel as csv and import that (will be much simpler).